# Как кроссбраузерно расположить фоновую картинку на весь экран?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Как расположить фоновую картинку на весь экран, чтобы это было кроссбраузерно по ie8 включительно?

Делаю по такому принципу, но встроенный эмулятор в ie edge и онлайн тестеры отображают криво или подвисают..

```css
#hero {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/1920x1080) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    hero.style.width = document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight + "px";
   </script>
    <![endif]-->
<div id="hero"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть мнение, что JQuery 2.x не поддерживает IE8-

http://jquery.com/download/

Могу предложить попробовать

```
hero.style.height = (document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight) + "px"
```

Единицы измерения vw и vh тоже не ладят с IE 8

http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: "Единицы измерения vw и vh тоже не ладят с IE 8" -именно поэтому и прописываю условие со скриптом :) @Alexey Kopantsev т.е. так имеете ввиду - изменения в примере выше

Comment: условный комментарий тут не нужен, можете убрать из стилей htight: 100vh, скрипт на JS отработает как надо, и к тому же не потребует подключения JQuery. На всякий случай уточню, что для корректной работы скрипта, как вы понимаете, нужно чтобы браузер уже построил DOM-модель хотя бы до того элемента, который нужно растянуть, поэтому подключение скрипта в HEAD работать не будет

Comment: так скрипт мне собственно нужен только для `ie8`, все остальные браузеры неплохо справляются с `height:100ch;` - зачем же лишний скрипт вешать для всех? а условный комментарий сработает перед закрытием `body`?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> background-size: cover;
> ```

Это не работает в IE8.

> ```
> hero.style.width = document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight + "px";
> ```

Тут в стиль прописывается невалидное значение. Скобок не хватает, как в соседнем ответе написали. Но я не понимаю, зачем это.

> Как расположить фоновую картинку на весь экран, чтобы это было кроссбраузерно по ie8 включительно?

Для IE8 надо класть тег img с абсолютным позиционированием.

Comment: "Но я не понимаю, зачем это." - для подсчета высоты экрана - у него ведь может быть различная высота - так ведь? "Для IE8 надо класть тег img с абсолютным позиционированием." и картинка будет на всю высоту, не ужатая/растянутая и не обрезанная? это как -поясните плиз

Comment: @Вася, сорри, не обратил внимание, что там cover и хотел растянуть. Подумаю ещё.

Comment: пардон, господа, забыл про скобки. код поправил. тяжелое утро было.

Comment: document.documentElement.clientHeight или document.body.clientHeight, в зависимости от браузера, получают значение высоты документа в числовом формате, дописываем "рх" и вставляем в стили

Answer (score 2):

А так?

```css
#hero {
  background: url("http://wpapers.ru/wallpapers/Music/8172/1920x1080_%D0%93%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0% 0%/cover;
width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://wpapers.ru/wallpapers/Music/8172/1920x1080_%D0%93%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://wpapers.ru/wallpapers/Music/8172/1920x1080_%D0%93%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
}
```

```html
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    hero.style.width = document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight + "px";
   </script>
    <![endif]-->
<div id="hero"></div>
```

Comment: а что собственно у вас получилось? вы видели результат? ничего не пойму..

Comment: "правильно размер фона ставить внутри фона, у вас он отдельно прописан background-size" - не вижу никакой проблемы, все корректно отображает и много где используется такой подход. @Arcadiy ну смотрите, что у вас получается - https://jsfiddle.net/08dyL07x/ Это совсем не то, что мне нужно! мне нужен фон, который будет помещаться ровно на весь экран без искажений и притом, чтобы он был кроссбраузерным. для всех браузеров кроме `ie8` у меня получилось сделать, а вот как с ним - пока остается загадкой..

Comment: "правильно размер фона ставить внутри фона, у вас он отдельно прописан background-size". кто это писал? можно ссылку на источники такой информации?

Comment: @Arcadiy хорошая попытка, но `ie` выдает ругается на `hero` - говорит, что его не знает..